# How to use Cofunction Identities to Find the Angle

Tags: trigonometry

Using cofunction identies, what steps can one take to find the angle *x* which makes the statement true?

> sec *x* = csc( 2 *x* + 45° )

MY ATTEMPTS :

I have tried rearrange sec *x* = csc( 95° + *x*), however, I am not sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint -

$\sec x = \csc(2x + 45°)$

$\csc(90° - x) = \csc(2x + 45°)$

$(90° - x) = (2x + 45°)$

Hope you proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: $$\cos x = \sin (2x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-2x-\frac{\pi}{4}) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{4}-2x)$$